# Connect file returns HTTP ERROR 500 instead of me using $conn->connect_error using PHP 8.1

Tags: php

The following code works fine in 7.3 (successful connection and when testing for an error).
However since changing to PHP 8.1 the page returns a HTTP 500 error and doesn't allow me to use the if $conn->connect_error line

```
    // Database settings
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_DATABASE = 'cascade';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASSWORD = 'root';
    const DB_PORT = '8889';

    // Salt encryption
    const SALT = '250b0623153be0e93d81c3ab1fe710f07d';

    // Connect
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, DB_PORT);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

When running the error logs I get the following:

````
[03-Nov-2023 14:08:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for localhostt failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/andrew/Sites/cascade/config.php on line 16
[03-Nov-2023 14:08:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for localhostt failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/andrew/Sites/cascade/config.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/andrew/Sites/cascade/config.php(16): mysqli->__construct('localhostt', 'root', 'root', 'cascade', '8889')
#1 /Users/andrew/Sites/cascade/index.php(11): include_once('/Users/andrew/S...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /Users/andrew/Sites/cascade/config.php on line 16```


Much help will be appreciated

I was expecting to use $conn->connect_error, but got a HTTP ERROR 500
````

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, check in `storage/logs`.  You can use a [try/catch block](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to catch everything except for fatal errors

Comment: @aynber I'm guessing I need to change how I trap errors? Pain the bum as works perfectly well in PHP 7 etc

Comment: Yes, using a try/catch block is a much better way of checking errors. As of PHP 8.1, [mysqli's default error mode is to throw exceptions](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/mysqli-error-mode)

Comment: @aynber - Thank you so much, it worked perfectly :)

Comment: @shingo - yep, I was forcing that error to fir $conn->>connect_error, however the code never got that fire as I got a HTTP 500 error

Answer (score 1):

The following code suggested by @aynber worked a treat:

```
try {
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE, DB_PORT);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        throw new Exception("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```